# Writing complex numbers in algebraic form

Tags: complex-numbers

Could someone give me one of these tasks as a "recipe"? I'm lost here.....

[image]

Comment: $\dfrac1{a+bi}=\dfrac{a-bi}{a^2+b^2}$

Comment: Okay, but how do I conjugate?

Comment: The conjugate of $a+bi$ is $a-bi$

Comment: I only did it with one fraction thus far. How do I do it with two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COMMENT.-Note that $i^2=-1,i^3=-i$ and $i^4=1$
$$z_1=\frac{(3+2i)(1+3i)}{13}+\frac{2i(3-i)}{10}\\ 
z_2=1-5(2i)+10(2i)^2-10(2i)^4+5(2i)^4-(2i)^5\\$$
For $z_3$ you have$$\frac{3-i^{99}}{i}=\frac{3i-i^{100}}{-1}\text{ and }\frac{2}{3+i^9}=\frac{2}{3+i}$$